# where is grub configured in ubuntu 10.04?

Tags: grub2, grub

I have an old Ubuntu computer coming in later today, and I suspect that I have to change some parameters of the grub configuration. I'm not sure if it is grub or grub2.
I have a VM of the system, but I haven't found the grub config files yet. I remember it used to be different. Im not sure if grub works the same way in a VM or if the conversion from a raw image to a VDI file modifies the bootloader.

the version of grub:

```
grub-install -v
grub-install (GNU GRUB 1.98-1ubuntu13)
```

I tried `locate menu.list` an unrelated python package shows up. I also looked for grub.conf, grub2.conf, and looked all around /boot for anything of evident significance.

where are the grub cofig files?

Comment: If really Lucid Lynx time for an upgrade to current version. And if that old of a system, you will need a lighter weight flavor to have system work well. https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours
Light weight flavors:
Lubuntu, xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, Budgie I think it was about 10.04 where they converted from grub (now grub legacy to grub2). but grub was .99, so if 1.98 that would be grub2. And then you have grub.cfg, but settings are in /etc/default/grub and in scripts /etc/grub.d. Then `sudo update-grub` creates new grub.cfg.

Comment: yeah, I mean if I could I would, but there are limiting factors, kernel 2.6 is the newest thing this device is going to run. It not like a regular PC, its a microwave. a robotic peptide synthisis accelerating microwave, with a custom set of PCBs that just so happen to be x86 compatible, It would be an absolute nightmare to try and reconfigure this thing on new hardware, if not completely impossible. anyway, I found it, its cfg, not conf, or config